# The problem of the creation msg when I learn as the tutorials(Creating a ROS msg and srv) in the ROS.org

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't understand the sentence "Also make sure you export the message runtime dependency."
[image description http://7xrn7f.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/16-3-13/11077439.jpg](http://7xrn7f.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/16-3-13/11077439.jpg)
The related files is in my google email:[link text](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-OKitZIRELKTWVKRWRGek0wVlU&usp=sharing)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228902/the-problem-of-the-creation-msg-when-i-learn-as-the-tutorials(creating-a-ros-msg-and-srv)-in-the-ros.org/) by [Fighting_bird](https://answers.ros.org/users/26255/fighting_bird/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2016-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The name of the file "AddTowInts.srv" is wrong in the CMakeLists.It should be "AddTwoInts.srv", so it appeared "Message service file not found" when building. It is a very stupid mistake!

---

Originally posted by [Fighting_bird](https://answers.ros.org/users/26255/fighting_bird/) with karma: 72 on 2016-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to add the line `message_runtime` to catkin_package
e.g.

```
catkin_package(
    CATKIN_DEPENDS
    message_runtime
)
```

BTW, you should also add to the `package.xml` file the following line

```
 <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
```

---

Originally posted by [Oded](https://answers.ros.org/users/21280/oded/) with karma: 105 on 2016-03-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fighting_bird](https://answers.ros.org/users/26255/fighting_bird/) on 2016-03-14**:
Thank you for your help. I did as what you said,  but it doesn't work.I couldn't find where errors are now! When I used `catkin_make install` in my catkin workspace, it outputed these:

```
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

**Comment by [Oded](https://answers.ros.org/users/21280/oded/) on 2016-03-14**:
I need more information to understand the source of the problem. maybe post the whole output.
Maybe [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/188096/failing-to-create-catkin-workspace/) can help you.

**Comment by [Oded](https://answers.ros.org/users/21280/oded/) on 2016-03-14**:
Can you post the CMakeLists.txt and package.xml files?

**Comment by [Fighting_bird](https://answers.ros.org/users/26255/fighting_bird/) on 2016-03-14**:
Yes,of course! But would you mind offerring your email?

**Comment by [Oded](https://answers.ros.org/users/21280/oded/) on 2016-03-14**:
Update you question and add the files. This way it could help others in the future.

**Comment by [Fighting_bird](https://answers.ros.org/users/26255/fighting_bird/) on 2016-03-14**:
I don't have enough points to upload files, so I share them in my google email.

**Comment by [Oded](https://answers.ros.org/users/21280/oded/) on 2016-03-14**:
Hmm... Everything looks in order.
Try running `catkin make install` a few times.
Sometimes it helps

**Comment by [Fighting_bird](https://answers.ros.org/users/26255/fighting_bird/) on 2016-03-17**:
I found the error!The name of the file `AddTowInts.srv` is wrong in the `CMakeLists`.It should be `AddTwoInts.srv`.